# Play/Pause callback not getting called when using MPRemoteCommandCenter

Tags: ios, swift, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am building a music player app, and everything is working fine. I have been using the system music player so far, but now want to switch over to use an application music player instead, and that's where I'm running into problems - for the life of me I can't figure out how to get my play/pause callback to be called from the iOS control center. Here's the code I'm using in my main view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer()

    self.registerForMediaPlayerNotifications()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()

    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.sharedCommandCenter()

    commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.enabled = false
    commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: "previousTrack")
    commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.enabled = false
    commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: "nextTrack")
    commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand.enabled = true
    commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: "playOrPauseMusic")
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: "playOrPauseMusic")
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.enabled = true
    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget(self, action: "playOrPauseMusic")
    commandCenter.playCommand.enabled = true

    [...]
}


func previousTrack() {
}

func nextTrack() {
}

func playOrPauseMusic() {
   print("playOrPause")
}
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of, is that your object does not exist anymore when the callback comes. Do you store the object somewhere?

Comment: You mean the commandCenter object? No I'm not storing this anywhere, as I assumed it would be some global shared instance for which I only need the reference to set targets / enable/disable etc. I can give this a try though...

Comment: No, I mean self, the object that contains this code. Put a breakpoint in its `dealloc` to see whether it gets cleaned up.

Comment: Oh.. Well this code is in my main view controller. The play/pause doesn't even work when swiping up to show the command center while this main view is displayed, so I guess it should definitely still exist at this point.

Comment: you have no need to call beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents when using MPRemoteCommandCenter.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you manage to solve it??

Comment: Nope, I ended up using the system music player instead

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue and noticed that the callback for `togglePlayPauseCommand` wasn't getting called, but `previousTrackCommand` was. So after some experimentation I got this working by removing `togglePlayPauseCommand` and instead indiviudally implementing the inline callbacks for `playCommand` and `pauseCommand` - please note that using custom selectors weren't working, they had to be the inline callbacks.

```
let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { (commandEvent) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
    moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
    moviePlayer.play()
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus.success
}

commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { (commandEvent) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
    moviePlayer.pause()
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus.success
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `Required background modes` to the Info.plist like this:

[image: Info.plist screenshot]

Answer (score -4):

place your code in viewDidApper.